# Linux implementation of Solaris doors

Tags: linux, solaris

I am porting some Solaris code to Linux.  This code uses the Solaris-specific door functions.

Is there a Linux equivalent?  I found a couple of examples but they don't appear to have been updated for many years.

http://www.rampant.org/doors

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ldoor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wiki says it is an RPC and Solaris-specific at that. On Linux for RPC you can use Corba for the purpose. Googling for "Linux Corba" shows lots of hits.

As portability apparently becomes a concern, first, before the actual porting, converting the application to use some portable RPC framework (Corba probably the most portable) makes a lot of sense. If portability isn't concern then the [D-Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) seems has became the de facto standard for the IPC on Linux.

[Door's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doors%5f%28computing%29) on Wikipedia also mentions that the mechanism also allows to pass list of file descriptors back and forth. On Linux check [`man 7 unix`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/unix) for SCM_RIGHTS.

Answer (score 2):

Solaris doors are a speed bastard. For example, call to the door in an another process shares the same process scheduler's timeslice of the caller. I really doubt you can get this with Corba and if doors in your application are used because of its speed, you may run into performance problems. I would suggest you to use another unix IPC(already mentioned shared memory, ... ), but that of course depends on your application.

Answer (score 1):

Linux does not have [doors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doors_(computing)), as you already know.  Doors are a kind of different RPC mechanism. You are pretty much going to have to recode using shared memory.  Or use an API.